# htaccess rewriterule whitout changing URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've a problem and hope u can help me whit this.

-I've multiple domains looking to the same IP.
-I've made rewriterules in htaccess but they change the URL to :
                       website1.nl/website1/index.php
-root looks like

```
    -web
       -website1
          -index.php
       -website2
           -index.php
```

-Iff i put the index.php in the root (map :web) i get a clean URL 
   just "website1.com" and no index.php

here's mine question :
How can i change this is htaccess whitout changing the URL?

what i get this far but isn't working is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I hope somebody can help me??????

Comment: why shouldn't it? `R=301` is FORCING the client to get redirected to the new url.

Comment: I realy dont now... google came up whit the answer and i still get the subdir behind mine URL like : wibsite1.com/website1/index.php...    what i want is redirected and a clean URL like website1.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!website1/).*)$ website1/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!website1/).*)$ website2/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: looks good i must say , but i see know that i made a problem for myself in using name's for subdir :)    name of site and name of subdir are the same :) i'm trying it now

Comment: Name of site same name of subdir isn't a problem at all.

Comment: Thanks works like a charm :) .... i got now  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!submap1/).*)$ submap1/$1 [NC,L],    but can u explain why submap1 is written in this rule twice????

Comment: `(?!submap1/)` is actually a negative lookahead regex that means route to `submap1/$1` only if request doesn't start with `submap1/`. This is to stop infinite looping.